# What relationships do spatial statistics share with time series analysis?

Tags: time-series, spatial, graphical-model, spatio-temporal

Spatial statistics is often discussed in tandem with time series. How are the two related? Do they share methodologies? Do overlap in assumptions or conditions of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A colleague of mine, J.K Ord, wrote a paper on this topic ([Ord 2010](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-01976-0_12)) where he chronicles the joint development of space and time analytics history.  He is a well known expert on time series analysis.  What time and space have in common is that both lead to observations that are not independent thus the need to transform the data.

Suitable transformations are often necessary in order to apply standard methodology. An example of this is the pre-whitening step in transfer function identification strategies leading to cross-correlations that are meaningful.